# Insightful books on differential equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, book-recommendation

What are some recommendations for insightful books on differential equations and difference equations? These books don't need to be in the format of a textbook, and don't need to provide the same topics as a textbook on ODEs might.

After reading such a book, one should be somewhat in awe of the subject. They shouldn't be pop-science-y however.

[See this question for inspiration on what answers should look like](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/828458/book-ref-request-starting-from-a-mathematically-amorphous-problem-and-comb).

Comment: "Qualitative Theory of Planar Differential Systems" by Dumortier, Freddy, Llibre, Jaume, Artés, Joan if you want to have some fun. For a complete and dense exposition (the best one as far as I know) see Coddington's "Theory of Ordinary Differential Equations". There's Chicone's book too for the same purpose of the later one. For an Eulerian style of math, there's always Arnold's book.

Comment: @user40276 What is an Eulerian style of math? I am not sure what "Arnold's book" is either. (sorry, don't have too much familiarity with existing mathematical literature)

Comment: I was just kidding. By Eulerian I meant in the way that Euler used to write, pretty incomplete and informal, but very insightful and inspiring.

Comment: @user40276 You have read some of Euler's works first hand? P.S. "Arnold" = "V. I. Arnold"?

Comment: The answer is no and yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a very subjective list:

- Arnold, [Mathematical Methods of Classical Mechanics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387968903) This book treats classical mechanics from mathematical point of view and introduces a wealth of various mathematical concepts (such as a differential manifold or differential form) in a *right* context. The main mathematical tool is ODE and it is really inspiring to see how they work to describe the physical reality.
- [Lectures on Analytic Differential Equations](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821836676) is written by two leading experts in the theory of analytic ODEs and brings you right to the frontier of the current research. This is not exactly a textbook, but a very well written research monograph that covers a lot of various topics pertinent to the *ordered* part of ODE theory (as opposed to the real of *chaos*).
- [Evolutionary Games and Population Dynamics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/052162570X). Do not be mislead by the title. This is quite an advanced book on applied ODE theory which treats a lot of mathematical techniques applied to genetics, population dynamics, and evolutionary problems. (There is a first edition, which is quite different, and which, to my taste, makes even better read).